# Internet Printing Protocol (IPP) get-server-version request?

Tags: python, ipp-protocol

I am writing a python IPP( Internet Printing Protocol) server.

If the client send a get-server-version request, how does the server response?

What is the format? Any document describes this?

thanks.

Comment: Where in the RFC/spec is "get-server-version" documented as a legal command?  Useful doc here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3196 and https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8011

Comment: What version do you refer to? The ipp protocol version the client talks to your server? Or maybe you want to tell the ipp client what 'version' your ipp server is running?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `get-server-version` request operation defined in ipp. Ipp clients usually check the printer using the operation `GET_PRINTER_ATTRIBUTES (0x000B)` and get an ipp encoded response like this (attributes already decoded):

```
ipp-versions-supported = [1.0, 1.1, 2.0]
printer-state = 3 {idle}
printer-state-reasons = toner-low-warning
printer-make-and-model = HP LaserJet 100 colorMFP M175nw
printer-info = HP LaserJet 100 colorMFP M175nw
printer-more-info = http://www.hp.com
...
```

For a reference starting point look into [RFC 2911](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2911) Section 3.2.5.2 Get-Printer-Attributes Response, Group 3: Printer Object Attributes and Section 4.3 Printer Description Attributes.